# How can I have separate columns of a dataframe out of list of tuples and a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following lists:

```
l1 = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
l2 = [7,8,9]
```

I want the output as df

df =

```
       c1 c2 c3

   0   1   2   7
   1   3   4   8
   2   5   6   9
```

So far I can separate out just the tuple as

```
df = pd.DataFrame(l1)
```

that gives me:

```
   c1  c2
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
```

I want to do for multiple lists of different forms as mentioned above.

Comment: `df['c3'] = l2` should do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also just use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), and concatenate the dataframes resulting from `pd.DataFrame(l1)` and `pd.Dataframe(l2)`:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(l1), pd.DataFrame(l2)], axis=1)

>>> df
   0  1  0
0  1  2  7
1  3  4  8
2  5  6  9
```

Comment: This you may generalise to any number of lists using a list comp, but all in all nice alt ;-)

Comment: `pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(l) for l in [l1, l2, ...]], axis=1)`

Comment: Yeah, I've actually used concat with a list comprehension like that before, and I was surprised at how *fast* it ended up being! I thought because of the explicit loop it would be slow for sure, but it ended up being my best bet

Answer (score 4):

2-list form:

```
pd.DataFrame([*x, y] for x, y in  zip(l1, l2))

   0  1  2
0  1  2  7
1  3  4  8
2  5  6  9
```

Multi-list form:

```
from collections import Sequence

lists = [l1, l2, ...]
pd.DataFrame([
    [
        k for j in i for k in (j 
        if isinstance(j, Sequence) else [j]
    )] 
    for i in zip(*lists)
])

   0  1  2
0  1  2  7
1  3  4  8
2  5  6  9
```

This will work for any case regardless of whether `l_i` is a list of tuples or list of integers.

Comment: @COLDSPEED: `pd.DataFrame([*x, y] for x, y in  zip(l1, l2))` this gives invalid syntax at `*x` position

Comment: @Atihska Yeah, my bad. I should have mentioned that's valid for python3.5+ only. OTOH the second should work for any version.