# Pandas, print variable in string

Tags: python, pandas, printing

I have a dataframe (new) that looks something like this:

```
num  name1  name2
11    A      AB
14    Y      YX
25    L      LS
39    Z      ZT
....
```

and I just want to extract the num value in a print statement such that I have an output that looks like this:

```
The value is 11
The value is 14
The value is 25
...
```

I'm not sure what the correct format to do this is, as the following bit of code just iterates "The value is".

```
 for index, row in new.iterrows():
     print('The value is').format(new['num'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slightly change your code

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print('The value is {0}'.format(row['num']))
    
The value is 11
The value is 14
The value is 25
The value is 39
```

With f-strings:

```py
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(f"The value is {row['num']}")
```

To print multiple columns, using dot notation:

```py
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(f"{row.name1} and {row.name2} have a value of {row.num}")

A and AB have a value of 11
Y and YX have a value of 14
L and LS have a value of 25
Z and ZT have a value of 39
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `str.join` and f-strings

```
print('\n'.join(f'The value is {n}' for n in new.num))

The value is 11
The value is 14
The value is 25
The value is 39
```

---

A slight variant and more to show how to use the `print` function...

```
print(*(f'The value is {n}' for n in new.num), sep='\n')

The value is 11
The value is 14
The value is 25
The value is 39
```

Comment: Introducing python3.5+ features in my experience never seems to work well with OPs... https://stackoverflow.com/q/50194179/4909087

Comment: Yeah... well... at least non-OPs are free to appreciate it (-:

Answer (score 3):

You can loop directly through a `Series` object (unlike through a `DataFrame` object). This allows you to do:

```
for num in new['num']:
    print('The value is ' + str(num))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try following:

```
for val in new.num: print('This is ', val)
```

Result:

```
This is  11
This is  14
This is  25
This is  39
```